# XMPP Connection to Firebase Cloud Messaging Disconnects

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I connect to Firebase Cloud Messaging using XMPP the connection typically disconnects after approximately 10 minutes. What I find is that I have to keep sending an upstream message to FCM every few minutes to ensure the connection does not disconnect. Is this expected?

Comment: I think this part of Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol) can help you about the XMPP connection. Also, this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133756) explains that if you are using XMPP, you need an upstream message.
For more information, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream).

Comment: Not entirely sure, but maybe you're encountering what is mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol) under **Control Messages**: `Periodically, CCS needs to close down a connection to perform load balancing.`

Answer (score 1):

yes, that is the normal behavior according the documentation of the XMPP protocol [link to XMPP documentation](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-silence)

> When an entity that is a party to a stream has not received any XMPP
> traffic from its stream peer for some period of time, the peer might
> appear to be silent. There are several reasons why this might happen:
>
> 1. The underlying TCP connection is dead.
> 2. The XML stream is broken despite the fact that the underlying TCP
>    connection is alive.
> 3. The peer is idle and simply has not sent any XMPP traffic over its
>    XML stream to the entity.

the traditional approach for solving this issue has been periodically to send so-called "whitespace pings" over the XML stream